# presenting viewController with transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

is it possible to define a type of transition when I instantiate and present a viewcontroller?

This code generates a default fade type transition, but I need it to appear from left to right, is it possible?

Thank you!

```
@IBAction func botonVolverFamilias(_ sender: Any) {
    let sw  = revealViewController()
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw
    let viewControllerModelos = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc_catalogo_familias") as! VC_catalogo
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerModelos)
    navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden=false
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    sw!.setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I've actually got code that, when pushing a view controller into a navigation stack, it swipes from left to right, or right to left.

Comment: Let me add it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may go with Following,

```
 let sw  = revealViewController()
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw
        let viewControllerModelos = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc_catalogo_familias") as! VC_catalogo
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerModelos)
        navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden=false
        navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
     let trans = CATransition()
            trans.duration = 0.5
            trans.type = kCATransitionPush
            trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
            trans.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            sw.view.window!.layer.add(trans, forKey: kCATransition)
        sw!.setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use to change the transition for a `UINavigationController` is find the first `UIViewController` in your stack. You should make an extension of this `UIViewController` as an `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and an `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

You can then call `func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` to define what sort of transition you want to present new `UIViewControllers` with.

So, in order to do this, we have to create a custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` class and return it in this `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` method. Here is the example of the one I use.

```
import UIKit

class SimpleOver: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    var direction: TransitionDirection!

    init(direction: TransitionDirection) {
        self.direction = direction
    }


    var popStyle: Bool = false

    func transitionDuration(
    using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.20
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        if popStyle {

            animatePop(using: transitionContext)
            return
        }

        let fz = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
        let tz = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!

        let f = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: tz)

        let fOff = f.offsetBy(dx: f.width, dy: 0)
        tz.view.frame = fOff

        transitionContext.containerView.insertSubview(tz.view, aboveSubview: fz.view)

        UIView.animate(
        withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
        animations: {
                tz.view.frame = f
                for subview in fz.view.subviews {
                    subview.alpha = 0
                }
        }, completion: {_ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }

    func animatePop(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let fz = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
        let tz = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!

        let f = transitionContext.initialFrame(for: fz)
        let fOffPop = f.offsetBy(dx: f.width, dy: 0)

        transitionContext.containerView.insertSubview(tz.view, belowSubview: fz.view)

        UIView.animate(
        withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
        animations: {
                fz.view.frame = fOffPop
                for subview in tz.view.subviews {
                    subview.alpha = 1
                }
        }, completion: {_ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }
}

enum TransitionDirection {
    case left
    case right
}
```

Then, within our `func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` method, we can simply return this `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` as so:

```
extension YourViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(
    _ navigationController: UINavigationController,
    animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation,
    from fromVC: UIViewController,
    to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        //This tells our navigation controller the style that we want to animate our transition between view controllers

        let simpleOver = SimpleOver(direction: .right)
        simpleOver.popStyle = (operation == .pop)
        return simpleOver
    }
}
```